# Please help me to solve this confusing probability question

Tags: probability

> Alex and Bobby are two students from a classroom which has 40
>   students. The teacher is going to choose 20 students from the
>   classroom for being "The Lucky Team". "The Lucky Team" is choosen by
>   dividing 40 students to 20 group. Each group is going to throw a coin
>   to decide who will be choosen to "The Lucky Team". If the probability
>   of Alex and Bobby to be choosen to "The Lucky Team" is $\frac{a}{b}$
>   which a and b are coprime, then what is a + b ?

I still confused with the sentence that said : *Each group is going to throw a coin to decide who will be choosen to "The Lucky Team". If the probability of Alex and Bobby to be choosen to "The Lucky Team" is $\frac{a}{b}$ which a and b are coprime...*

How can I translate that sentence into the math equation? I'm totally blank about the number of ways *Alex and Bobby to be choosen to "The Lucky Team"* can happen. Please... I will be happy and be grateful if you can answer this question. I will learn the solution so I can understand the abstraction of this question. :)

Thank's

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i'm new here :D. I forget to put my try on the question xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sentence is basically just a way to turn a fraction into an integer, im assuming you are imputing this in on website, and so its just easier to get you to enter in a number thats easy to read instead of parsing 
"8/11" for example. The bit about $a$ and $b$ being coprime, is so there is a single unique answer. Otherwise $\frac{2}{4}$ and $\frac{6}{12}$ which are both equal, give you different answers of $6$ and $18$. So they are just saying you have to reduce the fraction before you ad $a$ and $b$.

Assuming the twenty groups are drawn at random, then the probability that Alex and Bobby are in the same group is

$\cfrac{1}{\binom{40}{2}} = \frac{1}{780}$

Since there is only 1 way for them to be a group, and $\binom{40}{2}$ possible groups

If they are on the same team, them obviously they both cant be on the lucky team. So the probability they are both on the lucky team is the pr0obability they are on a different tream multiplied by the probability they both win their coin flip.

$\cfrac{779}{780}\left( \cfrac{1}{2} \cdot \cfrac{1}{2} \right) = \cfrac{779}{3120}$

So $789 + 3120 = 3909$

Answer (score 0):

Here is one interpretation:

If Alex and Bobby are in the same group then they can't both be chosen for the Lucky Team, so the probability is $0$ and there are no co-prime integers $a, b$ with $\frac{a}{b} = 0$.

Otherwise, the probability they are both chosen is $\frac{1}{4}$.

So, assuming that the probability that both Alex and Bobby are chosen for the Lucky Team is $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$, we can conclude that they are in different groups and that $a+b = 5$.

Comment: Actually, it seems that $\text{gcd}(0,1) = 1$...  So we should account for that case too as the other answers are doing.